# Why is React useEffect clean-up function being run right after the useEffect callback, and then never again?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a small React app with a component that has a button that opens a small menu, and I'd like it to close the menu when the user clicks anywhere outside the component.

```js
function setupDocumentClickEffect(onClick = (() => {})) {
  console.log('Add doc click');
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  return () => { // Clean-up
    console.log('Remove doc click');
    document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  };
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // Set up an effect that will close the component if clicking on the document outside the component
  if (open) {
    const close = () => { setOpen(false); };
    useEffect(setupDocumentClickEffect(close), [open]);
  }

  const stopProp = (event) => { event.stopPropagation(); };
  const toggleOpen = () => { setOpen(!open); };
  // ...
  // returns an html interface that calls stopProp if clicked on the component itself,
  // or toggleOpen if clicked on a specific button.
}
```

When the component is first opened, it will run both the callback and the cleanup immediately. Console will show: `Add doc click` and `Remove doc click`. If the component is closed and then re-opened, it acts as expected with just `Add doc click`, not running clean-up... but then clean-up is never run again.

I suspect I'll have to re-structure this so it doesn't use `if (open)`, and instead runs `useEffect` each time? But I'm not sure why the clean-up runs the way it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are wrong here. The first argument to a `useEffect` should be a callback function, which you're returning from `setupDocumentClickEffect`, this means that the return value of `setupDocumentClickEffect(close)` will just be run immediately on mount, and never again.

It should look more like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!open) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('Add doc click');
  document.addEventListener('click', close);
  return () => { // Clean-up
    console.log('Remove doc click');
    document.removeEventListener('click', close);
  };
}, [open]);
```

The other thing that is wrong here is that you are breaking the rules of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

You should not define a hook in a conditional.

EDIT

To elaborate on what is happening in your current `useEffect`, it basically boils down to if you wrote something like this:

```js
if (open) {
    const close = () => { setOpen(false); };
    console.log('Add doc click');
    document.addEventListener('click', close);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Remove doc click');
      document.removeEventListener('click', close);
    }, [open]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would want to throw that function inside of the `useEffect()` hook and avail yourself of `useRef` like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ options, selected }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
  const setupDocumentClickEffect = (event) => {
    // this if conditional logic assumes React v17
    if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

   document.body.addEventListener('click', setupDocumentClickEffect);

   return () => {
     document.body.removeEventListener('click', setupDocumentClickEffect);
   };
  }, []);
}
```

So since it's a menu, I imagine you build your list via a `map()` function somewhere that in this example, I am calling `options` which is why you see it passed as props in your `MyComponent` and you want to render that list of options from the menu:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ label, options, selected, onSelectedChange }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
  const setupDocumentClickEffect = (event) => {
    // this if conditional logic assumes React v17
    if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

   document.body.addEventListener('click', setupDocumentClickEffect);

   return () => {
     document.body.removeEventListener('click', setupDocumentClickEffect);
   };
  }, []);

  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    if (option.value === selected.value) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div 
       key={option.value}
       className="item"
       onClick={() => {
        onSelectedChange(option);
       }}
      >
       {option.label}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="ui form">
     // the rest of your JSX code here including
     // renderedOptions below
     {renderedOptions}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

So I added some props to your `MyComponent` and also showed you how to implement that `useRef` which will be important in pulling this off as well.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it's because you're calling `setupDocumentClickEffect(close)` immediately inside of `useEffect()`. Using a deferred call like `useEffect(() => setupDocumentClickEffect(close), [])` is what you want.

It might not break the useEffect hook, but it would be better practice to incorporate your `if(open)` within `setupDocumentClickEffect()` instead of wrapping your hook in it.